# Set background in Tkinter

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, background, frame

I was wondering if it's possible to set a background image on a frame in Tkinter.
I tried by setting a canvas inside a `Frame`, with an image, but it did not succeed to import.

```
def background(self):
    my_background = Canvas(self.__Frame4, bg="black")
    filename = PhotoImage(file=r"images\main_bg.png")
    background_label = Label(self.__Frame4, image=filename)
    background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
    my_background.pack(expand=1, fill=BOTH)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "did  not succeed t import"? You don't "import" images.

Comment: Read [Why does Tkinter image not show up if created in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16424553/7414759)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of imported image in a Label :

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

def create_img(frame, path_to_img):
    width = 100
    height = 140

    img = Image.open(path_to_img)
    img = img.resize((width,height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    photoImg =  ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

    img_label = tk.Label(frame, image=photoImg, width=width)
    img_label.image = photoImg
    return img_label

root = tk.Tk()
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1, minsize=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1, minsize=1)

my_image = create_img(root, "images\main_bg.png")
my_image.grid(row=1, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```